# PHP Associative Array count & extract

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got the following array

```
$array = [
            1 => 'test',
            2 => 'test',
            3 => 'test',
            4 => 'another'
        ];
```

What i want to obtain from this is:

1. The count of value 'test' $values (It's variable);
2. After that i will need to get all keys for value 'test' do to the next assumption:

```
if (\count($values) > 1) {
// do something with keys of value 'test'
 echo $keysOfThatValue;
}
```

3. I will need to do the upper assumption to all of the array elements grouped by array value.

Comment: Please post your code along with any errors you might get

Comment: I don't have a code, this is what i want to write. But i don't figgure out how to do :-?

Comment: At least try something. "Simplest" would be to iterate over the array ([foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)), if a value is "test", update a counter variable, maybe also save the key for later

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys` with a search argument, then just `count` those:

```
$count = count($keys = array_keys($array, 'test'));
```

Or following your code.  The `if` only executes if `test` is found and keys are returned:

```
if($keys = array_keys($array, 'test')) {
    // do something with $keys of value 'test'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) can be used to get an array of only entries with the value "test".